# Root Privilegs for NSTask in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, root, osx-elcapitan, nstask

I searched a lot on the web to find a simple way to get root privileges in my NSTask but I only found old articles which are written in Objective-C. But my Xcode Project is written in Swift :x is there a way to solve this problem to run a NSTask with Root Privilegs? :) I know I have to use something like AppleScript, STPrivilegedTask or the BetterAuthorizationSample from Apple but all I've found is written in Objective-C...

My Idea is to create a application that makes a storage media bootable with the command `createinstallmedia` :p all works perfectly the only problem is that the command wants root privileges, for testing I simply open my Terminal and login as Root but this is not the greatest solution for this Problem :D so please help me! :o

My Code the only thing that miss is the code to get root access:

```
import Cocoa


class ViewController: NSViewController {

var Task = NSTask()
var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()

var workingpath_createinstallmedia : String!
var workingpath_medium : String!
var workingpath_application : String!

var volume_flag = "--volume"
var applicationpath_flag = "--applicationpath"
var nointeraction_flag = "--nointeraction"

var commandpath : String!
var postcommand : [String]!

var DirectoryOS : NSURL!
var DirectoryMedium : NSURL!

@IBOutlet weak var PathControlOS: NSPathControl!

@IBOutlet weak var PathControlMedium: NSPathControl!

@IBOutlet weak var Outputlabel: NSTextField!

@IBAction func OSauswählen(sender: AnyObject) {

    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

    if openPanel.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK {

        DirectoryOS = openPanel.URLs[0] as NSURL
        PathControlOS.objectValue = DirectoryOS

}
}

@IBAction func Mediumauswählen(sender: AnyObject) {

    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

    if openPanel.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK {

        DirectoryMedium = openPanel.URLs[0] as NSURL
        PathControlMedium.objectValue = DirectoryMedium


    }
}

@IBAction func starttask(sender: AnyObject) {

    //                      edit Strings

    // Createinstallmedia

    workingpath_createinstallmedia = String(DirectoryOS)
    workingpath_createinstallmedia = workingpath_createinstallmedia.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")
    workingpath_application = workingpath_createinstallmedia.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%20", withString: " ")
    workingpath_createinstallmedia = workingpath_application + "/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia"

    // Medium

    workingpath_medium = String(DirectoryMedium)
    workingpath_medium = workingpath_medium.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("file://", withString: "")
    workingpath_medium = workingpath_medium.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%20", withString: " ")

    // config Task Parameters

    commandpath = workingpath_createinstallmedia
    postcommand = [volume_flag,workingpath_medium,applicationpath_flag,workingpath_application,nointeraction_flag]

    // commit the Parameters to the Task

    Task.launchPath = commandpath
    Task.arguments = postcommand

    // start Task

    Task.launch()
    Task.waitUntilExit()

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Have you tried translating *any of them* to Swift?

Comment: Yes of course, I tried to solve this with AppleScript and with a function called SMJobBless(). But nothing worked for me...

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm writing installer in swift, and I'd love to get access to use process with root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using sudo into the command and asking to the user for the password to give directly to the sudo, in the following way:

```
echo "passwordhere" | sudo -S command --arguments
```

and doing this using the sh shell executable to run the process, using this method i successfully created an app to create bootable mac os install media called TINU, but you need to be careful while dealing with user password, i chose to make my app open source to let others know what it does with this kinds of tasks that needs user password, but on mac os you should create specialized programs that does this kind of privileged tasks and then start them using system apis that will manage authentication for you and let the specialized program to do his job.